# Как сделать функцию, обратную данной?

Tags: функции, переменные

К примеру, есть некая f(x), которая даёт переменной x значение от 1 до 5 в зависимости от того, равна переменная 2, 3, 4, 5 или 6. Как сделать без геморроя функцию, которая давать x значение от 2 до 6 в зависимости от того, равен он 1, 2, 3, 4 или 5?

Comment: Чем вам `x + 1` не угодил?

Comment: нет, то, что я написал - это пример. У меня гораздо более длинная функция и я заколебусь, пока делаю такую же, но наоборот

Comment: В общем случае задача неразрешима. Далеко не у всех функций (и я бы даже сказал что у большинства) обратной функции просто нет

Answer (score 1):

В таком абстрактном случае, не зная того, как именно из входных данных получаются выходные - никак.

Если же есть таблица, например:

```
Вход    Выход
  2        4
  3        1
  4        2
  5        5
  6        3
```

то очень просто. Поменять местами вход и выход.

Answer (score 0):

математически. из f(x) делаем f(y) то есть

```
x=y+1
y=x-1
```